# rspec-email - How to get the body text?

Tags: rspec, rspec2, email-spec

I'm using rspec with the email-spec gem. I'm trying to do:

```
last_delivery = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
last_delivery.body.should include "This is the text of the email"
```

But that doesn't work, is there a way to say body, text version? Content-Type: text/text?

Thanks

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Body is actually a [Mail::Body](https://github.com/mikel/mail/blob/master/lib/mail/body.rb) instance. Calling raw_source on it should do the trick:

```
last_delivery = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
last_delivery.body.raw_source.should include "This is the text of the email"
```

Comment: Just a quick side note: if you're using multi-part e-mails, you first need to select the correct part like so: `last_delivery.parts.first.body.raw_source.should include "This is the text of the email"`

Comment: You juste made my day @PascalLindelauf! Thanks

Comment: Read the comment save my day :))))))))

Comment: This comment also saved me an hour of work @PascalLindelauf - thank you!

Answer (score 20):

After trying all the above options and failing to get it working (Rails 3.2.13), I found some info in [the ruby guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html) (section 6 is on testing with TestUnit) and got this to work exactly as needed:

```
last_delivery = ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.last
last_delivery.encoded.should include("This is the text of the email")
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: This can actually fail when the encoded mail contains line breaks marked by "=" like "This is the=\ntext of the email"

Comment: yes, but you can delete those new lines with:

last_delivery.encoded.should.delete("=\n")

Answer (score 10):

If you have an html template (*example.html.erb*) you could use:

```
last_delivery.html_part.body.to_s
```

Or, if you have a plain-text (*example.text.erb*) template:

```
last_delivery.text_part.body.to_s
```

Source: [In Rails why is my mail body empty only in my test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29454102/in-rails-why-is-my-mail-body-empty-only-in-my-test)

Answer (score 5):

you can just call `#to_s` on it.

```
last_delivery.to_s.should include "This is the text of the email"
```

For multipart emails:

```
last_delivery.first.to_s.should include "This is the text of the email"
```

Tested & found to be working on Rails 4

Comment: multi-part e-mails, you first need to select the correct part. Updated the answer. if this doesn't work. Let me know

Answer (score 5):

Generic way to get body text:

```
(mail.html_part || mail.text_part || mail).body.decoded
```

If an email is multipart (`mail.multipart?`) then its `mail.html_part` or `mail.text_part` are defined, otherwise they are nil and `mail.body.decoded` returns email's content.

You can use also `body.to_s` instead of `body.decoded`.

Answer (score 0):

In Rails 4 the default `last_delivery.body.should include "This is the text of the email"` works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is no need to send a mail in order to test the content.
You could just test:

```
expect(YourMailer.mail_to_test.body).to include "your string"
```

Answer (score -2):

```
expect(last_delivery).to have_body_text(/This is the text of the email/)
```

[source](https://github.com/bmabey/email-spec#have_body_texttext)

Comment: `has_body_text` is not a method for email