# In Rails why is my mail body empty only in my test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, email, actionmailer, minitest

I have an actionmailer class and associated overhead, it works perfectly. In my unit test (rails default minitest) however, the email body is empty. Why is that?

my mailer class:

```
class TermsMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: "info@domain.com"
  def notice_email(user,filename)
    @user = user
    @file = filename
    mail(to: "info@domain.com", subject: 'Data downloaded')
  end
end
```

my test:

```
require 'test_helper'

class TermsMailerTest < ActionMailer::TestCase
  test "notice" do
    email = TermsMailer.notice_email(users(:me),'file.ext').deliver_now
    assert_not ActionMailer::Base.deliveries.empty?
    assert_equal ['info@domain.com'], email.from
    assert_equal ['info@domain.com'], email.to
    assert_equal 'Data downloaded', email.subject
    assert_equal 'arbitrary garbage for comparison', email.body.to_s
  end
end
```

The views for this mailer are not blank, and the correct contents are in fact sent in the emails. So why is the email body blank in my test?

Comment: Use `email.body.encoded`. I would post this as an answer, but I don't remember why I had to make that change.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You probably have two versions of the email templates (`text.erb` and `html.erb`).

If so, you can use `email.text_part.body.to_s` for plain-text email and `email.html_part.body.to_s` for HTML version.

Comment: Where do you do this? My layouts weren't generated when I used the mailer generator so I don't know what it should look like